# Find volume of crossed cylinders without calculus.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, puzzle, volume, faq

I found this puzzle [here](http://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/%7Ewwu/riddles/hard.shtml).  (It's labeled "crossed cylinders".)  Here's the description:

> Two cylinders of equal radius are intersected at right angles as shown at left. Find the volume of the intersection between the two cylinders, *without using calculus!* A 3D picture of the intersection is shown at right.
>
> [image] [image]
>
> Hint (medium hint - exactly which high school formulae you need): 1) Area of circle = pi * radius2, and 2) Volume of sphere = (4/3) * pi * radius3
>
> Note: Solved by the mathematician Archimedes (287 B.C. - 212 B.C.), waaay before calculus came around!!

Please tell me how to solve this puzzle!  Is there a way to do this without setting up a Riemann sum and finding a limit, essentially evaluating an integral?

Comment: This post is chosen to be the [target for duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) for finding the volume of Steinmetz solid without using calculus. For the the calculus approach, please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249).

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8905/356647) with arguably better content.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Compare the solid to a sphere of the same size. The slices of the solid are squares to the sphere's circles, so the ratio of areas is always $4/\pi$. The volumes must therefore be in the same ratio, giving $(4/\pi) \cdot (4/3)\pi r^3 = (16/3) r^3$.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using prismoidal formula. Area at the Middle of the intersectcion is a square with sides 2r, so the area is 4r^2. Then the area at the top and bottom is 0. The length of the area of intersection is the diameter of cylinder equal to 2r.

Prismoidal formula. 
V= L*(Atop +4Amid + Abot)/6 
V= 2r(0+4*4r^2+0)/6 =(16/3) * r^3