# Volume of Solid Bounded by the cylinders $y=x^2$ and $y=z^2$ and the plane $y=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the volume of the solid bounded by the cylinders $y=x^2, y=z^2$ and the plane $y=1$

I think the integral should be: $$\int_0^1\int_{-\sqrt y}^\sqrt y\int_{-\sqrt y}^\sqrt y\ dx\,dz\,dy$$

Could someone tell me if this is correct?

Comment: Would your integral have been any different for $y=x^4$ and $y=z^4$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I made a typo on the integral limits. Should have been $-\sqrt y \, to \sqrt y$. Is it correct now?

Comment: @user116056 Corrected my typo on the integral limits. Is it correct now?

Comment: That looks more like it -- though using a double integral to calculate the area of _a square_ with known side length is rather overkill ...

Answer (score 1):

This is not quite right. The region of integration there is not curved but straight like this:

[image: how it looks]

Instead, maybe to

> use cylindrical coordinates.

Also please look at this question here: [Find the volume common to two circular cylinders, each with radius r, if the axes of the cylinders intersect at right angles. (using disk/washer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494249/116056).