# What is the intersection of these two cylinders?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

$$0\le x^2 + z^2 \le 1$$

$$0 \le y^2 + z^2 \le 1$$

I want to compute the volume of the intersection.

Sketching it out on paper is sort of nice: I see cross-sections that are disks, the first cylinder, the y-coordinate is free to vary, and for the second cylinder, the x-coordinate is free to vary.

The intersection, I would guess, seems to be something spherical.

So how can I pin down the actual set of points?

Well, one thing I thought of was to try to manipulate both inequalities to make use of the equation of a sphere, so I try looking at these inequalities instead:

$$y^2\le x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1 +y^2$$

$$x^2 \le x^2 +y^2 + z^2 \le 1+x^2$$

Am I heading in the right direction?  Where can I go from here?

Thanks,

Comment: It's definitely not a sphere, not sure you can say much more about it than it's the intersection of two perpendicular cylinders.

Comment: Hi Professor Grant, thanks for your comment, and especially for noting the orthogonality relationship.  I think I am almost there...

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intersection of two cylinders is called a [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html). You can give a description of the edges of the solid by

$$x = \pm z, \quad y = \pm \sqrt{1 - z^2}$$

and use these to give corresponding inequalities.

Comment: Hi @user, thanks so much for your quick response.  Well, using the above inequalities, I *do* see these coming out:  $x  = +/- \sqrt{1-z^2}$ and $y  = +/- \sqrt{1-z^2}$.  How come you don't mention this guy: $x  = +/- \sqrt{1-z^2}$?  ... is it already like implied somewhere in your description?  Thanks,

Comment: Ooh @user, I think I see what you are saying ...

Comment: So my above comment, I have basically found my integration limits for both x and y...is that correct, @user?  And now, I just have to find the integration limits for $z$ ...

Comment: But, solving for $z$ in each inequality gives us *two* upper and lower limits of integration, which is strange, @user ...

Comment: Perhaps the limits for $z$ is simply +/- 1, since the cross-sections are disks of radius 1, @user ... what do you think? Thanks,

Comment: Steinmetz is the German word for stone mason by the way.

Comment: Ooh, I got the right answer, @user :-)  Thanks again for the helpful discussion :-)

Comment: @user301446 Sorry - unfortunately my power went out rather couple minutes after I posted (I love winter). It seems you got everything worked out, though.

Comment: oh, no worries at all.  Yeap, I think I got it; thanks again :-)

Comment: And stay warm @user :-)

Comment: Please note the Wolfram's illustration is a bit misleading: in the first pair of pictures the right solid's orientation corresponds to two 'horizontal' cylinders crossing, not a vertical with a horizontal one, as depicted on the left image.

Answer (score 9):

I could not resist to model this in GeoGebra.

[image: Steinmetz solid]

Zenith is $(0, 0, 1)$ and nadir $(0, 0, -1)$.
A slice at height $z$ is a square with side length
$$
a = 2 \sqrt{1-z^2}
$$
so 
$$
dV = (2 \sqrt{1-z^2})^2 dz = 4(1-z^2) dz
$$
[image: slices]

Comment: haha...@mvw, thanks so much.  I am practicing for exams, so I think I had better pin down the algebra on paper for now.  Hmm...so the intersection is indeed *not* spherical, as Professor Grant points out in his comment above...

Comment: I hoped its surface intersection operation could deal with this one, but that is either too much yet for GeoGebra or I am doing something wrong.