# the volume of the solid limited by the surfaces $x^2+z^2=4$ and $y^2+z^2=4$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I want to find the volume of the solid limited by the surfaces $x^2+z^2=4$ and $y^2+z^2=4$.

I have broken the volume into sixteen pieces, one of which can be represented by the following section:

$0\leq x \leq 2 $

$0\leq y \leq x $

$0\leq z \leq \sqrt{4-y^2} $

Whenever I integrate over this section, I get a volume with $\pi$, whilst the answer I want is $\dfrac{128}{3}$.

I used the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt(4-y^2) dydx$$

I solved this with trig substitution, which left me with an inverse sin which went to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Is this the intersection of two cylinders?

Comment: Yes, it is. I should have said.

The problem has been reduced to one half of the volume in the 1st octant.

Comment: I've edited your latex slightly (last line); let me know if that broke anything. Why don;t you show us your work that led to the answer "$\pi$"? That way, we can perhaps help you learn how to debug such things.

Comment: It seems ok, John.

Comment: If you either want $z$ from $0$ to $\sqrt {4-x^2}$, or $y$ from $x$ to $2.$  As these are two cylinders intersecting, I would also consider cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: This sort of shapes is known as [Steinmetz solid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinmetzSolid.html). If you intersect two cylinders with radius $r$ whose axes intersect perpendicularly, the volume is known to be $\frac{16}{3} r^3$.

Comment: This comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The region of integration is even with respect all variables, thus
$$V=8\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}dxdydz$$
$$V=8\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{4-z^2}}\sqrt{4-z^2}dydz$$
$$V=8\int_{0}^{2}(4-z^2)dz$$
$$V=8(4z-\frac{1}{3}z^3)|_{0}^{2}=\frac {128}{3} $$

Comment: Thanks Behrouz. Can you, or anyone, explain why I don't need to consider the projection in the xy plane here?

Comment: As Doug M said, you can consider the projection in the $xy$ plane, but if you consider the region $\{(x,y)\;|\;0\le x\le 2, 0\le y\le x\}$, than $z$ ranges from $0$ to $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ (and not $\sqrt{4-y^2}$).

Comment: Please Note $-\sqrt{4-z^2}\le x \le \sqrt{4-z^2}$ and $-\sqrt{4-z^2}\le y\le +\sqrt{4-z^2}$. Since  region of integration $D=\{(x,y,z)|-\sqrt{4-z^2}\le x \le \sqrt{4-z^2},-\sqrt{4-z^2}\le y\le +\sqrt{4-z^2}, -2\le z\le 2\}$ is even with respect all variables, thus $\iiint_{D}dV=8\iiint $