# Intersection of two cylinders

Tags: calculus

What is the easiest way to find the area of the surface created when the cylinder $$x^2+z^2=1\text {  intersects the cylinder  }y^2+z^2=1.$$

I have used double integrals and also line integrals to find the area of  the surface created when the cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$ intersects $ y^2+z^2=1.$

The line integral is much easier than the double integral. Is there a way to find this surface area without using integrals?

Comment: See [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid).

Comment: Very interesting article. I was thinking on the same line of thought but could not quite figure it out.

Comment: Aside from the existing links, this comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
  R &= \{ 0<x<1,-x<y<x,z=\sqrt{1-x^2} \} \\
  S &= 8\iint_R dA \\
  z &= \sqrt{1-x^2} \\
  z_x &= -\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
  z_y &= 0 \\
  dA &= \sqrt{1+z_x^2+z_y^2} \, dx \, dy \\
  &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \, dy \\
  S &= 8\int_{0}^{1} \int_{-x}^{x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dy \, dx \\
  S &= 8\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx \\
    &= 16
\end{align}

See also ancient Chinese work, *Nine Chapters*《九章算術》commented by **Liu Hui**(劉徽) [**here**](https://liuhuimathmatician.wordpress.com/tag/steinmetz-solid/).

**Addendum**
[image]
In the figure above, the intersections between two cylinders (yellow and cyan) are two ellipses, namely $$x^2=y^2=1-z^2$$

Consider the purple region $T=\{ 0<y<x<1,x=\sqrt{1-z^2} \}$ which is bounded by a semi-circle in $xz$-plane and a semi-ellipse namely

$$(x,y,z)=(\sin \theta,\sin \theta,\cos \theta)$$

Now unwrapping the cylinder,
$$s=\theta \implies y=\sin s$$
therefore we get a sine curve (green).

[image: ![enter image description here]

The area of purple region $T$ is

$$\int_0^\pi \sin \theta \, d\theta=2$$

which is $\dfrac{1}{8}$ of the total surface area.

Comment: The correct answer does not depend on $\pi $

Comment: I need to double check, be patient!

Comment: Thank you. I was asking for a method which does not use integration.

Comment: Corrected, try to search for Archimedes' Method.

Comment: You have the correct answer now, but you have used integrals..

Comment: I leave it for other readers' reference.  See **Liu Hiu's** work in *"Nine chapters"* [**here**](https://liuhuimathmatician.wordpress.com/tag/steinmetz-solid/)

Comment: @Ng Chung Tak can you please explain how did you get that the expression you used is the enclosed surface? I am also stuck in this question and cannot understand the solution. Please

Comment: @Guji2203, **addendum**, with diagrams, is appended in my answer.