# Form the double integrals of the case given

Tags: calculus

Form the double integrals to calculate the volume of an object inside the cylinder $x^2+z^2=a^2$ and $x^2+y^2=a^2$

I have a trouble to form the double integrals of this problem. The first one I can't imagine what is the base plane of the object so I can't determine the lower and upper bound of each integrals. Also,  now how to determine the function we need to integrate? 
I have seen some articles discussing about double integration problems,  but I don't have any idea to solve this one. Do I need to form $z = \pm \sqrt{a^2 - x^2}$ or what? Please help.  Regards.

Comment: This solid is called a *bicylinder*.  Some research into that term might help you visualize the solid and develop an integral.

Comment: Closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2599749/265466.

Comment: Aside from the existing links, this comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a picture of your solid.

It is called a "Steinmetz solid"

[image]

Convert to cylindrical.
Since $x$ is in both equations let x be "odd man out."

$z = r\cos \theta\\
y = r\sin \theta\\
x = x\\
dx\ dy\ dz = r\ dx\ dr\ d\theta$

$x^2 = a^2 - r^2 \cos^2\theta$ when $\cos \theta \ge \sin\theta$ and $x^2 = a^2 - r^2 \sin^2\theta$ otherwise.

Use symmetry to your advantage

And that should be enough to get you on your way.