# Calculate the area of the shape bounded by $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2+z^2=a^2$ using multiple integrals

Tags: integration, analysis, multiple-integral

I need to calculate the shape area bounded with $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and  $x^2+z^2=a^2$. Given that I have a 3-D shape, I assumed that area would be calculated using a triple integral, but done that way, I get the volume of the shape.

So, my question is: how do I get the area of the shape using integrals?

I tried observing it in 2-D, but it does not have the same shape as in the space. It's more of a projected shape that does not give me anything useful.
Also, I tried using spherical coordinates, but then again it is used for calculating the volume.

Comment: Do you want the surface area?

Comment: [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid)

Comment: You may want to go through this https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calciii/surfaceintegrals.aspx

Comment: Please refer to my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2599749/intersection-of-two-cylinders/2599963#2599963).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $r > 0$, the solid:

$$
\Omega := \left\{(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 \le r^2, \, x^2 + z^2 \le r^2\right\}
$$

is the intersection between two circular cylinders of radius $r$ and with perpendicular axes:

[image]

In particular, noting the three symmetries enjoyed by solid $\Omega$:

$$
(x,\,y,\,z) = \mathcal{S}(-x,\,y,\,z)\,,
\quad \quad
(x,\,y,\,z) = \mathcal{S}(x,\,-y,\,z)\,,
\quad \quad
(x,\,y,\,z) = \mathcal{S}(x,\,y,\,-z)
$$

the measure of this solid is equal to:

$$
||\Omega|| := \iiint\limits_{\Omega} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
= 2^3\iiint\limits_{\Omega^*} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
$$

where:

$$
\Omega^* := \left\{(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 \le r^2, \, x^2 + z^2 \le r^2, \, x \ge 0, \, y \ge 0, \, z \ge 0\right\}.
$$

This done, through a coordinate transformation of the type:

$$
\small
(x,\,y,\,z) = (u\,r\,\cos v,\,u\,r\,\sin v,\,w)
\quad \text{with} \;
(u,\,v,\,w) \in \left[0,\,1\right] \times \left[0,\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right] \times \left[0,\,r\sqrt{1 - u^2\cos^2 v}\right]
$$

we have:

$$
||\Omega|| = 8\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\,\text{d}v \int_0^1 r^2\,u\,\text{d}u \int_0^{r\sqrt{1-u^2\cos^2 v}} \text{d}w = \frac{16}{3}\,r^3\,.
$$

---

As for the boundary of solid $\Omega$, we have:

$$
\partial\Omega := \Sigma_1 \cup \Sigma_2
$$

where:

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \Sigma_1 := \left\{(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 = r^2, \, x^2 + z^2 \le r^2\right\}; \\
\\
& \Sigma_2 := \left\{(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + z^2 = r^2, \, x^2 + y^2 \le r^2\right\}; \\
\end{aligned}
$$

which for the above symmetries implies:

$$
||\partial\Omega|| := \iint\limits_{\partial\Omega} 1\,\text{d}\Omega = 2\iint\limits_{\partial\Sigma_1} 1\,\text{d}\Sigma = 2 \cdot 2^3 \iint\limits_{\partial\Sigma_1^*} 1\,\text{d}\Sigma
$$

where:

$$
\Sigma_1^* := \left\{(x,\,y,\,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 :  x^2 + y^2 = r^2, \, x^2 + z^2 \le r^2, \, x \ge 0, \, y \ge 0, \, z \ge 0\right\}.
$$

This done, through a coordinate transformation of the type:

$$
(x,\,y,\,z) = (r\,\cos v,\,r\,\sin v,\,u)
\quad \text{with} \;
(u,\,v) \in \left[0,\,r\,\sin v\right] \times \left[0,\,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]
$$

we have:

$$
||\partial\Omega|| = 16 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \text{d}v \int_0^{r\sin v} r\,\text{d}u = 16\,r^2\,.
$$

---

All this verifies what has been reported about the [Steinmetz solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinmetz_solid), as noted in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be a lot more straightforward. How would you find the surface area of a cylinder $x^2+y^2=a^2$ of radius $a$ between bounds of $z$ that are constant values $z_1, z_2$? As you already know, it is $2 \pi a |z_2 - z_1|$ and it comes from integral $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{z_1}^{z_2} a \ dz \ d\theta$. We evaluate the same integral here but $z$ is now a function of $\theta$. So coming back to the problem at hand, let's first consider the surface area of cylinder $x^2+y^2 = a^2$ bound by the cylinder $x^2+z^2 = a^2$.

We parametrize the surface of the cylinder $x^2+y^2 = a^2$ as $r(\theta, z) = (a \cos\theta, a \sin\theta, z)$. Bound of $z$ from $x^2+z^2 = a^2$ is given by $ - a |\sin\theta| \leq z \leq a |\sin\theta|$

So integral to find surface area is

$S_1 = \displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-a |\sin\theta|}^{a |\sin\theta|} a \ dz \ d\theta = 8a^2$

Due to symmetry surface area of cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = a^2$ bound by cylinder $x^2+y^2 = a^2$ is the same.

That results in a final answer of $S = S_1 + S_2 = 16a^2$.

Comment: I had shared a link on surface integral earlier. That helps you understand how to find surface area in general, not sure if you are already familiar with it. But in case of a cylinder (the case here), it is lot more straightforward. In this problem, the only difference is that the height of the cylinder is not constant and changes based on $\theta$. Also you have surface area of two cylinders to evaluate and sum them for total surface area.

Answer (score 0):

When you say *Area* is it safe to assume you mean surface area?

The shape in question is the intersection between two cylinders, one centred around the $z$ axis with radius $a$ and the other centred around the $y$ axis with radius $a$. Since the radii are equal I think this simplifies it somewhat. I just plotted it in GeoGebra to see what it looks like.

What you get is:
$$|z|\le\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
$$|y|\le \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$
$$|x|\le a$$

Comment: Yes, surface area is what I meant, sorry for my lousy English.                                             This still does not answer my question though, I used GeoGebra as well but still I don't know how to calculate the surface area and which formula should be used for its calculation?

Comment: since it is symmetric try looking at one quadrant then multiplying

Answer (score 0):

Consider development of the elliptic area as under a sine curve

Area of sine curve $ y= \sin x (x,0, \pi/2) $ is unity

From symmetry, there are eight such areas.

Area under sine curve/ Bounding rectangle area  fraction being $2/\pi,$

$$ 8 \cdot \pi r . r\cdot \frac {2}{\pi} = 16 r^2.$$