# Volume of intersection of cylinders using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration

Use a double integral to find the volume of the solid bounded by two surfaces $$x^2+y^2=4,$$ and $$x^2+z^2=4.$$

is it using one way to integrate or there is using separation way?

Comment: you don't need calculus to solve this problem, see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/237911/59379) for a related question.

Comment: if i want to use the integral way to solve it, can you give me some hint ?

Comment: You can translate above answer to a triple integral and then integrate over $y$ and $z$ first... i.e.
$$\int_{-2}^2 
\left[ \
\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}
\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}
dy dz 
\right] dx$$

Comment: can i use polar coordinates to do it ?
will it be easier to solve right?

Comment: You can use polar coordinates but it will be a bad choice for this particular problem. The integral over $y$ and $z$ above give you 4(4-x^2), integrating a polynomial is much simpler than integrating any trigonometric function.

Comment: can u show me your working ?

Comment: Aside from the existing links, this comment is to link this post as one of the [(abstract) duplicates](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868) to the current choice of [mother/target post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494249).